# Procedure returning -1 regardless of array being sorted

Tags: arrays, assembly, procedure

I'm currently writing a procedure in Assembly to see if an array is sorted. Here is my code:

```
.DATA

inputIntMessage BYTE "Enter an integer: ", 0
intArray     DWORD  4 DUP (?)
integerInput DWORD   ?
sorted DWORD ?

.CODE
main PROC
;Here is where I insert whatever the user input into the array
mov eax, 0
mov ecx, LENGTHOF intArray
L1:
    intInput inputIntMessage, integerInput ;This is the user input
    mov ebx, integerInput
    mov intArray[eax*4], ebx
    inc eax
    loop L1

call if_sorted
intOutput sorted
INVOKE ExitProcess, 0


if_sorted PROC
    mov esi, OFFSET intArray
    mov ebx, 0
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intArray

    L2: 
        mov eax, [esi + TYPE intArray * ebx]
        inc ebx
        cmp eax, [esi+ TYPE intArray * ebx]
        jle less_than_or_equal
        jg greater_than
    less_than_or_equal:
        mov sorted, 1
        loop L2
    greater_than:
        mov sorted, -1
    ret
if_sorted endp

main ENDP
```

The if_sorted procedure returns 1 or -1 based on if the array is sorted (1 if the array is sorted, and -1 if it is not). I have run through the debugger and when the array is sorted, the debugger goes to the line `call if_sorted` and then instantly goes to `intOutput sorted` and outputs -1 (when it should have ran through the if_sorted procedure). When the array is not sorted, the debugger goes to the line `call if_sorted` and properly runs through the procedure, and outputs -1. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you mean to exit your program after `intOutput sorted`? As it is once it prints out the value it will continue execution running what is in the procedue `if_sorted`

Comment: So I would write `main ENDP` after `intOutput sorted`? But if the array is sorted then it doesn't run through `if_sorted` at all before printing `sorted` There is a second part to this problem (which I have yet to write because of this problem), which is to print out the elements of the array if the array is sorted, and if the array is not sorted then the program would prompt the user to enter numbers once again. But as it is right now, it will constantly ask for new numbers because it always returns -1

Comment: No you need to do proper shutdown to exit your program otherwise it will just keep executing whatever code exists below it (which would likely execute the code in the procedure below it.

Comment: But what I want is for the program to execute if_sorted and _then_ do `intOutput sorted`. It is backwards right now.

Comment: Well I am trying to fix on glaring error that will cause issues.

Comment: When you used the debugger to execute `call if_sorted` did you use the debugger to step over the call or step into it? You need to step into a function or it will just execute the function and run to the line just after the call.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by proper shutdown (I am still a beginner at assembly). Do you mean `INVOKE ExitProcess, 0`? If so, I will edit that in.

Comment: Yes at `ExitProcess` but it needs to go on the line after you output the integer `intOutput sorted`. Not at the very end.

Comment: As such? I have now added `ExitProcess after `intOutput sorted`

Comment: Yes, now I asked a question about how you were debugging your function. Do you step into your function or step over it in the debugger?

Comment: I used Step Over in the debugger

Comment: You need to use step into on a function call to step through the function line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it! What I had forgotten is to put a `ret` after the loop finished, so:

```
less_than_or_equal:
        mov sorted, 1
        loop L2
        ret
    greater_than:
        mov sorted, -1
        ret
```

Once I included that the procedure worked fine.